# JavaScrip Validar que cargo una peticion

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

En mi codigo mando a llamar una pagina php cada 2 segundos con Jquery, soy nuevo en esto, estoy validando como seria la mejor forma tengo algo asi,

```
<div id="identificador">

<script>
setInterval('load', 2000);

function load(){

$('#identificador').load('pagina.php');

 </script>
```

de que manera podria validar que la pagina cargo?, para seguir llamandola sin que queden las peticiones en el aire ya que (pagina.php) hace una conexion a una base de datos para validar informacio. ! que no puedo usar ajax para hacerlo.

el problema es que despues de unos minutos quedan casi todas en (pending)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pásale una función callback al método `load()`, es función será llamada cuando se cargue la página. Puede servirte para saber cuándo volver a llamar la página.

```
$( "#identificador" ).load( "pagina.php", function() {
   //código a ejecutar cuando la página se haya cargado
});
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias Me sirvio mucho